# How to replace deprecated withServerTransition in Angular 16?

Tags: angular, angular16

In Angular 16, `withServerTransition` is deprecated. How can I replace it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybf8o.png).

I tried the following code:

```
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  { provide: APP_ID, useValue: 'serverApp' },
  ...
],
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Type '{ provide: InjectionToken<string>; useValue: string; }' is not assignable to type 'any[] | Type<any> | ModuleWithProviders<{}>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'provide' does not exist in type 'any[] | Type<any> | ModuleWithProviders<{}>'.ts(2322)
(property) provide: InjectionToken<string>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You almost got it right, this should go in the `providers` object instead of the `import`

```
providers : [{ provide: APP_ID, useValue: 'serverApp' }],
```

Comment: BrowserModule we need to remove ?

Comment: No, keep the `BrowserModule` import but move the providers into the providers !

Comment: After adding in providers, what are the modules inside the imports, it showing error

Comment: What  error message do you get ?

Comment: src/app/app.module.ts:39:9 - error NG6002: This import contains errors, which may affect components that depend on this NgModule.

39         SharedComponentsModule,

Comment: You likely have an error with `SharedComponentsModule`

Comment: yes, iam getting error on that

Comment: BrowserModule,
        {
            provide: APP_ID,
            useValue: 'serverApp',
        },
like this we need to add in providers

Comment: sorry, now its working
Actually I upgrade ngx-pagenation in package.json